# Как спарсить ники всех пользователей?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup

Поставил себе задачу спарсить ники всех пользователей с форума https://forum.dirt.ru/, посмотрел курс по парсингу от Олега Молчанова, но осталось много вопросов на которые не могу найти ответы...

Как "научить" парсер переходить с темы на тему? Как вообще подобраться к нику без `id` и `class` в `BeatifulSoup`?
Как вы ищите ответы на свои вопросы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По-моему ваша задача решается гораздо проще - в цикле читаете информацию о всех пользователях, увеличивая ID пользователя на единицу:

Эмпирическим путем установлено, что на данный момент [последний пользователь имеет ID: 76039](https://forum.dirt.ru/member.php?u=76039)

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное!

Comment: ярчайший пример The XY Problem :) ps 80099 на 27.05.2021

Comment: @Jack_oS, ну не такой уж он и яркий - здесь бывали "ярчеЕ" :-D